# Error handling on the order of resolution of dependent methods in python

Tags: python, error-handling, coding-style

I am writing a python API and the reccurent exception is that some methods are not meant to be run before others by the user itself.

Here is an example of the context in its simplest formulation:

```
class myclass(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.x = None

    def method1(self):

        self.x = 1

    def method2(self):

        if self.x is None:
            raise Exception('myclass.method1 should be called first')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = myclass()

    # method2 raise the error because method1 was not called first
    a.method2()
```

My question is pretty simple : how should I name `Exception`?

I couldn't find an appropriate name in the python built-in exceptions, so should I derived an `CustomError` directly from `Exception`? How should I name `CustomError`? Is there a standard name in programming that I could use to define generally a wrong order in methods calls ?

Comment: looks like a ValueError to me - maybe subclass that.

Comment: Yeah agree with @wwii. subclass it `class BadCallError(ValueError): pass`

Comment: I guess it is the best choice regarding the description even if ValueError is not very semantic for the user and it needs renaming. I was hesitating with NameError, or more specifically UnboundLocalError (because without referencing it in __init__, it would be unbound), or even TypeError, because I just noticed that is was thrown in the `abc` module when it cannot solve the resolution order.